# MVC 4.0 Clearing output cache using HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, caching

I am trying to implement caching in an MVC 4.0 ASP.net application.  I can cache using outputcache

```
[OutputCache (Duration=60)]
public ActionResult myaction(string parm1)
{
     --logic to construct the model object
     -- followed by this return statement

     return PartialView(model);
}
```

But I need to clear the cache after editing data which is stored in an xml file.

So I tried to add

```
HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem(Url.Action("myaction", "myController"));
```

in another action of the same controller before calling  `return RedirectToAction(myaction);`

But the cache is not getting reset.

Is this the method to refresh outputcache using actions?  I call these actions from jquery using ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ICacheProvider](http://stevescodingblog.co.uk/net4-caching-with-mvc/) instead.
`OutputCache` is very limited on what you can do.

Once you need to change the data that is cached, you can invalidate that particular data using `ICacheProvider` while using `OutputCache`, you either cache the entire `ActionResult` or none.

Also `OutputCache` does neither have the flexibility that `ICacheProvider` has, nor the beauty of working with it.

Comment: Thank you.  I was able to get caching added to my application with the ICacheProvider; But I also would like the capability of clearing the whole cache, not just one entry in the cache using a key.  I couldn't figure out a way to loop through the cache; Is that possible to loop through the object cache/ memory cache to clear the whole cache?

Answer (score 0):

You may have cached the output on the user's machine instead of the server. Try specifying the Location:

```
[OutputCache(Location= System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Server, Duration=60]
```

Otherwise the cache deletion won't work because you've cached the HTML output on the user's machine

Comment: Thanks Jason for the quick response;  I have tried adding the location also, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC supports donut-hole caching but not donut caching. You can cache partial views and exclude parent view BUT you cannot cache parent view and exclude partial views. Write a custom filter for caching or use https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcDonutCaching